# Target [Dingo\Api\Contract\Routing\Adapter] is not instantiable while building [Dingo\Api\Routing\Router] error on Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, dingo-api

I was trying ti use Dingo package with Lumen.
But unfortunately while setting up routes ,
its showing following error.
Target [Dingo\Api\Contract\Routing\Adapter] is not instantiable while building [Dingo\Api\Routing\Router] error on Lumen

Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

## Routes.php

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');


$api->version('v1', function($api){
    $api->get('users', function(){
       return 'test';
    });
});
```

Comment: Ensure your config/app.php has "Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks man:)
After 4 years your solution is still useful:) It just needs a little modification.

`$app->register(\Dingo\Api\Provider\LumenServiceProvider::class);`
in /bootstrap/app.php

It helped me with Lumen 7.0 and DingoApi 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the issue. I added `Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class` at the end of `bootstrap/app.php`.

Thats why this issue has happened.